# No space left on device while I still have 640GB of free space

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I was copying some huge files from a remote disk to my computer and got a message

> No space left on device

I installed my Ubuntu 12.04 in my 640GB HDD and thought that Ubuntu was utilizing all of its space but it seems not from this error message.

I checked the space with **'disk usage analyzer'** and the result says

> Total filesystem capacity: **658.2 GB** (used: 28.9GB available: 629.2GB)

I checked again with **'disk utility'.** And I found out that only 19GB is spared for the root and the rest is mounted at some place called **/host**.

I installed Ubuntu in 640GB and hoped it would utilize the full disk space, but it looks like it some how occupied only about 20 GB of the 640GB HDD and left the rest of the space mounted at **/host**.

How can I resolve this problem? Could anybody give me a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You installed using the Windows Ubuntu Installer (Wubi). This means Ubuntu is not installed to your harddisk like a normal install, but instead uses a file in the Windows filesystem to simulate a harddisk. /host is your Windows host system, which contains that file.

I would recommend that if you intend to keep using Ubuntu, you install it using a memory stick or CD/DVD directly onto your harddisk. You can also resize the harddisk image file manually and then resize Ubuntus filesystem, but this must be done from a live session in any case. It's probably both faster and easier to just install it using the normal (non-Windows) installer. Just copy your /home directory to some place else, and copy it back after the reinstall. That way, all your settings and files will still be available.